# How to operate on the second level of a multidimensional array in php?

Tags: php

I have to take out average marks of the class in the following example:

```
<?php
$class = array(
    "stu1"=>array(
        "marks"=>50,
        "grade"=>C
    ),
    "stu2"=>array(
        "marks"=>70,
        "grade"=>D
    ),
    "stu3"=>array(
        "marks"=>85,
        "grade"=>A
    ),
);
```

I am unable to sum the marks of all the students.

without using any built-in functions would be preferred.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with a simple foreach loop:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($class as $student)
    $sum += $student["marks"];
```

with `array_sum`:

```
$sum = array_sum(array_column($class,"marks"));
```

Comment: Thanks. I was using 2 foreach loops and was not able to get the answer.